# AVAssetExportSession video file exports with multiple audio tracks

Tags: ios, audio, video, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I'm using `AVAssetExportSession` with an `AVMutableComposition` to create one video file from three video files.

When inspecting the output video file in `Quicktime`, there are two audio tracks.

```
1. 2ch 44,100
2. 1ch 44,100
```

How can I export using `AVAssetExportSession` so that the exported video has only one audio track as this is causing a problem where the video is displayed outside of iOS.

I have used `SDAVAssetExportSession` which does what I'm after, but it has some reliability issues as seen on the Github issues for the project, so I would prefer to just use `AVAssetExportSession`.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this. I am facing the exact same problem and unsure about using SDAVAssetExportSession.